# My footer and navbar does not meet the device width in mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to adapt my website to mobile devices. Currently, my website works perfectly for desktops, however, there seems to be a persistent issue on the mobile devices in which the navbar and footer doesn't stretch to meet the full width of when the user is zoomed out.

Desktop:

[image: Desktop View]

Mobile:

[image: Mobile View]

Mobile Login:

[image: Mobile Login]

What's weird is that my login and signup page are perfect in meeting the device width, where have I gone wrong?

Base CSS (used in login):

```
html {
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 100%;
}

body {
    /*background-color: #09244d;*/
    background-image: url(../static/bg.jpg);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    }

.navbar a {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#footer {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: #343a40;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

    #footer .dev {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

Home CSS:

```
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 36px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

th, td {
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}

table.a {
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 180px;
}

th:first-of-type {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

th:last-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-of-type {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
    color: darkcyan;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    color: aquamarine;
}

.card {
    background: #272E48;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card label {
    color: white;
}

.form-control {
    border: 1px solid #596280;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: .825rem;
    background: #1A233A;
    color: #bcd0f7;
}


}
```

Viewport Header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I've also attempted many different settings such as user-scalable set to yes etc...

Navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link id="rating" href="/ratings">Ratings</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link id="settings" href="/settings">Settings</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Footer:

```
<div id="footer">
    <p class="dev">Developed by </p>
</div>
```

Comment: did you add `viewport` tag inside `<head> </head>`.??

Comment: @KunalTanwar Hi, yes I did

Comment: You didn't post the `navbar` and `footer` styling inside your code. Please post entire code or at least minimal code which can help us to understand better.

Comment: @KunalTanwar Sorry, I just added the code.

Comment: I was talking about the `CSS` part and also you are using any kind of framework like bootstrap etc?

Comment: @KunalTanwar The CSS I'm using is from base.css. And I'm currently using bootstrap 4.

Comment: Maybe some bug in `4.x` version I don't know much because I don't use any of these frontend frameworks keep these things apart. Try [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/) maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: @KunalTanwar Just changed it, same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Did you hosted it this website somewhere?? So I can take a better look.

Comment: @KunalTanwar Yes. thehackneyproject.co.uk

Comment: Well in my browser I am not seeing any issue like you explained or posted a reference image about.

Comment: @KunalTanwar I just changed the meta viewport that prevents scaling. It looks fine for now, but do you have any idea on how I can fix the box shadow? It looks horrible now

Comment: `box-shadow` of which element exactly?? Oh! it is dark on dark so I barely noticed it. Shadow looking horrible!? Bro it is not even visible. 